# How to programmatically submit a lightning-record-edit-form?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

The [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/specification) has a documented `submit` method that I assume can produce similar behavior to a click on a nested submit button. But I can't find any examples of this.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/specification) describes a `fields` argument for the `submit` method of:

> Submits the form using an array of record fields or field IDs. The
>   field ID is provisioned from @salesforce/schema/. Invoke this method
>   only after the load event.

When no argument is supplied to `submit`, features like required field validation does not work. I'm not in a position to test right now so am wondering:

- If the fields are hard-coded as the `submit` argument, does the expected behavior result?
- Can the field names specified in the nested `lightning-input-field` elements be programmatically obtained? (I note that `lightning-record-edit-form` has a `field-names` property but that is documented as "Reserved for internal use. Names of the fields to include in the form.".)

Comment: Check the last section *Overriding Default Behaviors*, that first code example in aura [recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation) docs.  `fields` seems to be the event parameter that contains all the fields

Comment: It's incredibly frustrating that we're provided with the `submit` method to call from outside of `lightning-record-edit-form` but the behavior is inconsistent with including an input or a button inside of the component. 1) the field validations do not fire and 2) if you have a submit handler (`onsubmit`) it isn't called! Additionally, there's no mechanism to grab the fields from a `lightning-record-edit-form` unless you use a querySelector or the fields are set dynamically from the JS side of the component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have run into this often since moving from Aura to lightning web components (LWC) and have found that the only solution is to hide a submit button on the form, and then call click on it from your JS method when desired.

A very basic example of this would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<template>
   <lightning-spinner if:false={rendered} 
                      alternative-text="loading..." 
                      variant="brand" 
                     size="small" >
   </lightning-spinner>
   <template if:true={rendered}>
       <lightning-record-edit-form onsubmit={handleSubmit}
                                   object-api-name="Account" >
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" ></lightning-input-field>
            <input type="submit" class="hidden" />
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
        <lightning-button onclick={submitMyformProgramatically} 
                          variant="brand" 
                          label="Click me" >
         </lightning-button>
    </template>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

  @track 
  rendered = false;

  connectedCallback(){
     this.rendered = true;
  }

  submitMyformProgramatically(){
     const btn = this.template.querySelector( ".hidden" );

     if( btn ){ 
        btn.click();
     }
  }

  handleFormSubmit( event ){
     const fields = event.detail.fields;
     console.log( "Fields: ", fields );
  }
```

}

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

in this example, a simple click of the external button will submit this form programatically by locating the button on the form and clicking it.

In Aura `lightning:recordEditform`, you used to be able to set an aura:id on the form and simply call `submit` from your JS, but that doesn't work in the new LWC `lightning-record-edit-form`

Comment: Thanks Ronnie, I didn't want to resort to that if there was a cleaner but more obscure way to do it.

Comment: I looked for something documented, found nothing. I too wanted a different way.

Comment: Nested button it shall be...

Comment: worked perfectly, I just found in time; I was about to spend too much effort in rebuilding the form

Answer (score 2):

You can call the submit method of the record-edit-form component directly. It is much cleaner than hiding a button.

```
this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit();
```

Comment: In my testing, that was not directly equivalent... but I can't remember what the difference was.

Comment: Trouble with this approach is that it does not trigger the onsubmit event.